# use part of Entity Framework (4+) to convert data types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

Is there any accessible code in the Entity Framework (version 4+) that I can use to convert .NET data types to SQL Server data types?

Taking that a step farther, is there some way to pass it a .NET type and get a full table definition in some kind of walkable tree?

Update 1: It seems that ModelConfiguration inside DbModelBuilder (v6) has what I want. However, that property is not exposed and the class is internal.

Comment: So confused on what you're asking. When working with EF you're able to use most of the data types and they are converted for you.

Comment: To clarify, I want to use part of EF but not the part that actually talks to the database. I want to use the model builder but not the database context.